# How to make an unfilled diamond using while loops in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I can only create a filled diamond, i can't figure out how to get it unfilled.`#

```
# The size of the diamond
N = 7

# The top part (includes the middle row)
i = 0
while i < N // 2 + 1:
    print((N // 2 - i) * " " + (2 * i + 1) * "*")
    i += 1

# The bottom part
i = 0
while i < N // 2:
    print(" " * (i + 1) + "*" * (N - 2 - 2 * i))
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# The size of the diamond
N = 7

# The top part (includes the middle row)
i = 0
while i < N // 2 + 1:
    print((N // 2 - i) * " " + "*" +( ((2 * i -1) * " " + "*") if i > 0 else ""))
    i += 1

# The bottom part
i = 0
while i < N // 2:
    print(" " * (i + 1) + "*" + ( ( " " * (N - 2 - 2 * i - 2) + "*") if i < (N//2-1) else ""))
    i += 1
```

simply print two less spaces than you were printing *'s inbetween two *'s unless on top or bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to print `(2*i-1)` spaces in between `'*'` characters instead instead of only `'*'`. And have to deal with the very top and very bottom separately:

```
# The size of the diamond
N = 7

# The top part (includes the middle row)
print((N // 2) * " " + '*')
i = 1
while i < N // 2 + 1:
    print((N // 2 - i) * " " + '*' + (2 * i - 1) * " " + '*')
    i += 1

# The bottom part
i = 0
while i < N // 2 - 1:
    print(" " * (i + 1) + '*' + " " * (N - 4 - 2 * i) + '*')
    i += 1
print((N // 2) * " " + '*')

   *
  * *
 *   *
*     *
 *   *
  * *
   *
```

Comment: oops, you beat me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def diamond(size, sym_func):
    s = ''
    for row in xrange(size):
        for column in xrange(size):
            if row > size//2: # if bottom half reflect top
                row = size - row - 1
            if column > size//2: # if right half reflect left
                column = size - column - 1
            s += sym_func(row,column,size)
        s+= '\n'
    return s

def solid(row,column,size):
    if column >= (size // 2 - row):
        return "*"
    return " "

def hollow(row,column,size):
    if column == (size // 2 - row):
        return "*"
    return " "

def circle(row,column,size):
    if (size//2-row)**2+(size//2-column)**2 <= (size//2)**2:
        return '*'
    return ' '

print diamond(size=7, sym_func=solid) # The size of the diamond
print diamond(size=7, sym_func=hollow) # The size of the diamond
print diamond(size=17, sym_func=circle) # The size of the diamond
```

look at the difference between the hollow and solid symbol functions if you use a >= then you get a solid thing if you use a == for exact comperison then it is just the parimiter

Comment: try def circle(row,column,size):
 if (size//2-row)**2+(size//2-column)**2 <= (size//2)**2:
  return '*'
 return ' '